# Ho to change chartArea BackgroundColor in a Google Charts?

Tags: google-visualization, background-color

I'm trying to use the chartArea.backgroundColor option of Google Charts, but it doesn't seem to work, although this option is clearly described in the doc : https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#Configuration_Options

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kf2h53ks/)

HTML :

```
 <div id="piechart1" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

JS :

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['Work',     11],
      ['Eat',      2],
      ['Commute',  2],
      ['Watch TV', 2],
      ['Sleep',    7]
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'My Daily Activities',
        chartArea: {'backgroundColor':'red'}
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart1'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Any clue ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @helloflash thanks for the edit, but I already put google-charts-api as a tag, but it seems to be a bug or a feature, as it it replaced by google-visualisation tag. I think it's an alias.

Comment: @Mathieu Thanks for the precision. Hope you'll have answers.

Comment: Why don´t you use directly the `backgroundColor` option?

Comment: because it changes the whole background (beneath title, legend...), and not only the chartArea one.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the official documentation
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#exploding-a-slice

**Use the `slices` attribute to change color of individual slice.**

updated code from fiddle

```
function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['Work',     11],
      ['Eat',      2],
      ['Commute',  2],
      ['Watch TV', 2],
      ['Sleep',    7]
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'My Daily Activities',
        slices: {
        0: {color:'red' },
        1: {color:'blue' },
        2: {color:'green'},
        3: {color:'black'},
        4: {color:'teal'}    
      },
        chartArea: {'backgroundColor':'red'}
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart1'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
```

}

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need to change the slice color. I want to change the color of the background, but only the background part beneath the pie, not beneath the title and legend. According to the doc, this is what "chartArea" is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
chart.draw(data, google.charts.PieChart.convertOptions(options));
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Comment: I get the error `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'google.charts.PieChart')` fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/kf2h53ks/1/